# Enable php SSH2 in in Bitnami Stack

Tags: bitnami

I want to enable de SSH2 module in PHP.

I am using **Bitnami Wordpress Stack**.

The [official docs](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/components/php/) say to run some commands to install **libssl-dev**.

But I don't know where that console is.

I tried the one that is under *Start* -> *Use Bitnami Wordpress Stack*.

But it would not recognize **sudo** as a command.

**Question**:

Is there not any other way to get SSH2 working? In case there is not... where do I find the right console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you need to follow the steps described on the documentation section [How to Install the SSH2 Module for PHP](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/components/php/#how-to-install-the-ssh2-module-for-php).

Please note that those instructions are intended for a Debian-based Operative System (like Debian or Ubuntu). When using a different Operative System (Windows, OS-X or a non-debian based Linux Distro) you still need to compile `libssh2` and `ssh2` but you can't use those commands.